# String Arrays: Delete original array and then return copy

Tags: c, arrays

I am new with C and I am trying to understand allocating strings.

I am trying to create a function called `adding_string`. It takes in an array of zero or more strings that has a null in the final location. Next, it makes a shallow copy of the array that is + 1 location bigger, then appends a copy of the string `str` onto the array. Finally, it deletes the original array and returns the new copy

This is what I have so far:

```
char **adding_string(char **array, const char *str)
{

    size_t num = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *final= (char *)malloc(num);
    strncpy(final, str, num);
    free(array);
    //The above code would create a copy of the string "str".
    //Then it puts that into the array.
    //Not sure if free(array); would be the right method
    //Having issues with returning final too

    return final;
}
```

In the `main` function, you would have something like:

```
char **array = NULL;
char **lines;

array = (char **)calloc(1, sizeof(char *));

array = adding_string(array, "help");
array = adding_string(array, "plz");
array = adding_string(array, "thanks");

for (lines = array; *lines; lines++)
{
    printf("%s\n", *lines);
}
```

I'm not sure if `free(array)` would be the right method to use to delete the original array, and I'm having issues with returning the new copy.

When I try returning the new copy, I get:

```
warning: return from incompatible pointer type
```

which is because of:

```
return final;
```

Comment: You aren't copying the array but just str. And final is of type `char*`, that's why it says "incompatible pointer type" - the functin is supposed to return `char**`.

Comment: .@rain city , that makes sense, thank you. Please correct me if I am wrong, but to fix this, I would have to do change the str to array, and then use strncat to add the two up. Next, I would return char**, which would be the array.

Comment: Why should *lines become null?

Comment: @QuasselKasper is a technique that emulates how cstrings are terminated by using a  `'\0'`-terminating byte. Here you have instead a `NULL` pointer. `argv` in `main` works in that way, the last element is `NULL`. The `execv` for example demand that as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `adding_string` makes no sense, you make a copy of `str`, free the memory
from `array` and return the new copy. The function should return a double pointer to `char`,
you are passing a single-pointer to `char`. All other values are lost, you are
leaking memory like crazy.

I'd rewrite your `adding_string` like this:

```
char **adding_string(char **array, const char *str)
{
    char **tmp;
    if(str == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // first make copy
    size_t len = strlen(str);
    char *strcopy = malloc(len+1);
    if(strcopy == NULL)
        return NULL;

    // you've allocated enough memory for the copy
    // no need of strncpy here
    strcpy(strcopy, str);

    // get the number of strings saved
    size_t size = 0; // number of strings saved
    if(array)
    {
        tmp = array;
        while(*(tmp++))
            size++;
    }

    // reallocate memory for array of strings
    tmp = realloc(array, (size+2) * sizeof *tmp);

    if(tmp == NULL)
    {
        // something went wrong, free the copy
        free(strcopy);
        return NULL;
    }

    tmp[size] = strcopy;
    tmp[size+1] = NULL;

    return tmp;
}
```

Note that in this version, if `array` is `NULL`, the function allocates the memory for the
array of strings. That's only a design choice, you could as well check that
`array` is not `NULL` and pass to `adding_string` a pre-allocated array of
strings. I think (and that's only my opinion) that is more elegant that
`adding_string` will create the first array. In this way, the code that
allocates memory is in one place only.

Now in your main

```
char **array = NULL;
char **lines;

// adding_string will allocate the memory for array when it's NULL
array = adding_string(array, "help");
array = adding_string(array, "plz");
array = adding_string(array, "thanks");

for (lines = array; *lines; lines++)
{
    printf("%s\n", *lines);
}
```

Note that I do

```
tmp = realloc(array, (size+2) * sizeof *tmp);
```

`size` has the number of strings saved, that means that `array`
holds `size+1` spaces, because the last one points to `NULL`. You are appending
one more strings, so you have to reallocate `size+1+1` spaces, which is
`size+2`.

Please don't forget to free the memory afterwards.

Comment: Thank you so much! This made a lot of sense!

Answer (score 1):

The program below strictly follows your needs and intentions.

The array `array` is resized every time a new string is added. At the end of the program the proper cleanup of all allocated memory is done.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char ** adding_string(char **array, const char *str)
{
    size_t num = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *final = (char *)malloc(num); // allocate memory for the string `str`
    strncpy(final, str, num);   // create the copy of the `str`  

    int i=0;
    for(i=0; array[i] !=NULL; i++) {}  // find how many elements do we have in the array

    array[i] = final; // add final to the first empty spot in the `array`
    i++;

    char ** new_array = calloc(1+i, sizeof(char *));  // allocate a new array 1 size bigger
    memcpy(new_array, array, sizeof(char*)*i);        // copy all the pointers

    free (array); // no need for the old array 

    return new_array; // return a pointer to the new bigger array
}

int main(void)
{
    char **array = NULL;
    char **lines;

    array = (char **)calloc(1, sizeof(char *)); // allocate array for 4 poiters if type (char *)

    array = adding_string(array, "help");
    array = adding_string(array, "plz");
    array = adding_string(array, "thanks");

    for (lines = array; *lines; lines++)
    {
       printf("%s\n", *lines);
       free(*lines);
    }

    free (array);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
help
plz
thanks
```

This is different approach where

```
char *adding_string(const char *str)
```

returns a pointer `(char *)` to the copy of the string. The `array` has already preallocated memory to accommodate all string pointers.

A small program to demonstrate the concept:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *adding_string(const char *str)
{

    size_t num = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *final= (char *)malloc(num); // allocate memory for the string str
    strncpy(final, str, num);   // crreate the copy 

    return final; // return a pointer to created copy
}


int main(void)
{
    char **array = NULL;

    array = (char **)calloc(4, sizeof(char *)); // allocate array for 4 pointers if type (char *)

    array[0] = adding_string("help");
    array[1] = adding_string("plz");
    array[2] = adding_string("thanks");

    for (int i=0; i<3; i++ )
    {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);
        free(array[i]);
    }

    free (array);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
help
plz
thanks
```